# Collapsing a dataframe according to duplicate values of a column and removing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a patient database with multiple lab values where every lab gets its own row, even if on the same date. I would like to collapse the rows based on duplicate dates for each patient in order to have one row per date which contains the results from all the labs that day.

I've tried a variety of `groupby()` and `pd.merge()` functions to no avail.

Toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
PID = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
ALC = [200, np.nan, np.nan, 300, np.nan, np.nan]
WBC = [np.nan, 1000, np.nan, np.nan, 2000, np.nan]
per_neut = [np.nan, np.nan, 0.64, np.nan, np.nan, 0.77]
date = ['11/1/18', '11/2/18', '11/2/18', '1/11/04', 
        '1/11/04','1/11/04']

prac_dict = {'PID':PID, 'date':date, 'ALC':ALC, 'WBC':WBC,
             'per_neut':per_neut}
pract_df = pd.DataFrame(prac_dict)
```

This is what I have

```py
print(pract_df)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0       NaN
2    1  11/2/18    NaN     NaN      0.64
3    2  1/11/04  300.0     NaN       NaN
4    2  1/11/04    NaN  2000.0       NaN
5    2  1/11/04    NaN     NaN      0.77
```

And this is what I want:

```py
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0      0.64
2    2  1/11/04  300.0  2000.0      0.77
```

Suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need first non missing values per groups per columns use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = pract_df.groupby(['PID','date'], as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0      0.64
2    2  1/11/04  300.0  2000.0      0.77
```

But if duplicated values per groups, like `50` in last group for `ALC` column is necessary specify aggregate function like `sum`, `mean`, if use `first` second value is lost:

```
PID = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
ALC = [200, np.nan, np.nan, 300, np.nan, 50]
WBC = [np.nan, 1000, np.nan, np.nan, 2000, np.nan]
per_neut = [np.nan, np.nan, 0.64, np.nan, np.nan, 0.77]
date = ['11/1/18', '11/2/18', '11/2/18', '1/11/04', 
        '1/11/04','1/11/04']

prac_dict = {'PID':PID, 'date':date, 'ALC':ALC, 'WBC':WBC,
             'per_neut':per_neut}
pract_df = pd.DataFrame(prac_dict)
print (pract_df)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0       NaN
2    1  11/2/18    NaN     NaN      0.64
3    2  1/11/04  300.0     NaN       NaN
4    2  1/11/04    NaN  2000.0       NaN
5    2  1/11/04   50.0     NaN      0.77
```

---

```
df1 = pract_df.groupby(['PID','date'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
print (df1)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0      0.64
2    2  1/11/04  350.0  2000.0      0.77

df2 = pract_df.groupby(['PID','date'], as_index=False).mean()
print (df2)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0      0.64
2    2  1/11/04  175.0  2000.0      0.77

df3 = pract_df.groupby(['PID','date'], as_index=False).first()
print (df3)
   PID     date    ALC     WBC  per_neut
0    1  11/1/18  200.0     NaN       NaN
1    1  11/2/18    NaN  1000.0      0.64
2    2  1/11/04  300.0  2000.0      0.77
```